# Populating a dropdown field using php

Tags: php, fetch

below code doesnot populate the list. i am trying populate a dropdown list from database but the below query doesnot populate the dropdownlist.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputLocation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">
<?php

$queryData = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cat_name as cat_name FROM 'categories' ORDER BY `cat_name`");
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($queryData));   //$result now has database tables
?>
<select name='cat_name'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>
        <option values=<?php echo($row['cat_name']); ?><?php echo($row['cat_name']); ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>  </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you seem to be calling mysql_query and fetching the array twice...

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($queryData);
```

Should be changed to

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($queryData);
```

Then further down, change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

To...

```
foreach($result as $row)
```

You can always do

```
print_r($result);
```

To ensure you are getting data back from the query.

You also have two select tags, one of which isn't closed. Remove this top one

```
            <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">
```

Couple of other points to note:

- The MySQL extension is depreciated, you should look into converting this query to MySQLi or PDO
- You don't need brackets around an echo statement, just use

  echo $variable;

Full edited code here

http://ideone.com/GASwcB

Comment: thanks Pete, but this doesnot work. i just get a field but no values in it. can you please give me the full working code? thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of print_r($result); ?

Comment: Thanks Pete for your help

Comment: No worries @Ranjit, if this has solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks